# Trying to display ½ in a WebView on Android and it shows Ȃ½

Tags: android, unicode, utf-8, webview

I have a WebView where I'm loading a string from a database. In that string there's a ½ character and when I go to look at it on my devce it's showing up as Ȃ½.  I tried using utf-8 and also unicode. I also tried searching for the Ȃ using Java string replace and replacing it with "", but it didn't work.

```
String description = "½";
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.loadData(description, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string provided to loadData() is loaded via a 'data: URL' and so needs
to be [URL-Encoded](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html)

*Credit: [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/2v9YlQWGvuY) via [Matt Murphy (CommonsGuy)](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware).*